# matplotlib modify outer x label and keep inner x label

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, axis-labels

I have a plot with 2 x_labels for two subplots. The inner x label is "Bronx, Brooklyn, Manhanttan, Queens, Staten Island"(or is it call x tick?), the outer x label is "borough":

[image: Original plot]

I want to find two different solutions to handle the "borough" labels.

1. Remove both "borough" label from the graph.
2. Keep 1 "borough" in the center of the two subplots.

The sample data is follow:

| borough | total_person_injured | total_person_killed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QUEENS | 1000 | 1000 |
| QUEENS | 2000 | 2000 |
| BROOKLYN | 1000 | 1000 |
| BRONX | 1000 | 1000 |
| MANHATTAN | 1000 | 1000 |
| STATEN ISLAND | 1000 | 1000 |

The code to generate the original plot is

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

df = pd.read_csv ("C:/file.csv")

fig, ax = plt.subplots (1,2)
plt.suptitle ("Collision injured verus killed per boroughs")

df_injured_killed = df.groupby ("borough")[["total_person_injured", "total_person_killed"]].sum()

ax[0].set_xticklabels (labels = df_injured_killed.index, rotation = 45)
ax[1].set_xticklabels (labels = df_injured_killed.index, rotation = 45)

# Future code will be add here

sb.barplot (x = df_injured_killed.index, y = df_injured_killed["total_person_injured"], ax = ax[0])
sb.barplot (x = df_injured_killed.index, y = df_injured_killed["total_person_killed"], ax = ax[1])
```

I had tried

```
ax[0].set_xlabel("")
ax[1].set_xlabel("")
```

and

```
ax[0].set(xlabel=None)
ax[1].set(xlabel=None)
```

and

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots (1,2, sharex=True)
```

Which had no effect on the graph.

I had tried

```
plt.axis("off")
```

Which remove inner and outer x labels for the right subplots:
[image: Missing x label on right subplot]

I had tried

```
ax1 = plt.axes()
x_axis = ax1.axes.get_xaxis()
x_axis.set_visible(False)
```

Which completely remove the graph from the plot:

[image: Missing graph plot]

I had tried

```
fig.text(0.5,0.001,"Borough",ha="center")
```

Which add more label:

[image: More label plot]

Comment: I would simply hide the x-label on both axes and place a `fig.text` in the middle of the figure.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just edit my question which is exactly what you describe. But the problem is how to hide x-label on both axes?

Comment: you need to put the `ax[0].set_xlabel('')` **AFTER** the `sb.barplot(...` calls

Comment: Yours works too! You should answer it so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn's barplot returns an axis-object, you just need to assign it to a variable and then use `set` to remove it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

df = pd.read_csv ("C:/file.csv")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
plt.suptitle("Collision injured verus killed per boroughs")

df_injured_killed = df.groupby("borough")[["total_person_injured", "total_person_killed"]].sum()

ax[0].set_xticklabels(labels=df_injured_killed.index, rotation=45)
ax[1].set_xticklabels(labels=df_injured_killed.index, rotation=45)

# Future code will be add here

plot1 = sb.barplot(x=df_injured_killed.index, y=df_injured_killed["total_person_injured"], ax=ax[0])
plot2 = sb.barplot(x=df_injured_killed.index, y=df_injured_killed["total_person_killed"], ax=ax[1])

plot1.set(xlabel="")
plot2.set(xlabel="")
fig.text(0.5, -0.15, "Borough", ha="center")
```

I also added `sharey=True` to subplots which makes it look a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works. But I can't use ```sharey=True``` since the two subplots magnitude difference is too large.